# assignment from incompatible pointer type c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 80 /* Maximum  length of command*/

struct memList
{
 char commandName[41];
 char restCommandName[41];
 struct List *next;
};



void addToList(char [], char [], int);

int main()
{
 char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1]; /* Command Line Argument*/
 int should_run=1, status, i, num;
 pid_t pid;
 char str[41], teststr[41];
 const char delimiter[2]=" ";
 char *token;


 while(should_run)
{
i=0;
printf("osh>");
fflush(stdout);

fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';
token=strtok(str, " ");

    while(token)
    {
       args[i]=strdup(token);
       printf("args[%d]=%s\n", i, args[i]);
       i++;
       token=strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    if(args[0]=="history")
    {
        addToList(args[0], str, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        addToList(args[0], str, 0);
    }
    pid=fork();
    if(pid<0)   // error in creating child process
    {
       printf("\tError in creating child process\n");
    }       
    else if(pid==0)    //child process will execute this block
    {
       printf("\tChild running it's block\n");

       execvp(args[0], args);
                 exit(1);
    }
    else        //parent process will execute this block
    {
       pid=wait(&status);
       printf("\tNow Parent resumes\n");

    if(!strcmp(args[0], "exit"))
    {
            should_run=0;
    }
}
}
return 0;
} 

void addToList(char cmd[], char restCmd[], int flag)
{
 int i;
 struct memList *head=NULL;          //In this function node is created
 struct memList *ptrNode=NULL;       // and added to the list
 struct memList *temp=NULL;
 ptrNode=(struct memList *)malloc(sizeof(struct memList));
 memset(ptrNode, 0, sizeof(struct memList));
 strcpy(ptrNode->commandName, cmd);
 strcpy(ptrNode->restCommandName, restCmd);
if(head==NULL)
{
 head=ptrNode;

}
else
{
 ptrNode->next=head->next;
 head=ptrNode;
}


if(flag)      //if flag=1 i.e. if args[0]=history then the whole list will get printed
{                //this block of code shows error
 temp=head;         //assignment for incompatible pointer type
 while(temp!=NULL)
 {
  printf("%d %s", i, temp->commandName);
  temp=temp->next;
 }
}
}
```

Please let me know if there are any other existing memory leaks in my code and the way I passed args[0] as argument to the function addToList(). Is that correct. If not, then how should I proceed on that.

Comment: Incompatiable*, not incomplete (in your comment). A compiler wouldn't complain about assignments of incomplete *pointer* types (just values).

Comment: `if(args[0]=="history")` that's not how you compare strings in C. Use `strcmp` or `strncmp`.

Comment: Defensive programming tip: use strncpy(destBuf, srcBuf, sizeof(destBuf)) instead of strcpy to defend against buffer overrun and other undefined behavior if user types in a longer word than you expected...

Comment: what if destBuf and srcBuf are of same size, then can we use sizeof(srcBuf)?

Comment: if sizeof(srcbuf) > sizeof(destBuf) then there's a problem; strncpy will only copy the as much of srcbuf as will fit into destbuf. You will also need to make sure there's room for the null character, since strncpy might have to stop before it gets to the end of the srcbuf string. So actually strncpy(destBuf, srcBuf, sizeof(destBuf)-1); destBuf[sizeof(destBuf)-1]='\0'; would be better.  Again just a tip for defensive programming, maybe not related to your compiler error.

Comment: struct memList member next should be struct memList* next -- not struct List.

Comment: The warning which was coming, now its gone. Thank You, the last comment worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that struct List* is a different pointer type than struct memList*, so temp=temp->next; gives a compiler error. (In gcc-4.7.2 the error message is: cannot convert 'List*' to 'memList*' in assignment)

Change struct memlist declaration as follows:

```
struct memList
{
    char commandName[41];
    char restCommandName[41];
    struct memList *next; // instead of struct List *next;
};
```